# How do I remove items from a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

So I'm trying to make a guessing game where you guess the name of a song using the first letter of each word, I've got the first word down but the next ones always display an extra '_' Can anyone help?

```
import random
import re
sWord = 0
correct = 0
lines = ["All Star-Smash Mouth", "Don't Stop Believin'-Journey", "Mr. Brightside-The Killers"]
song = random.choice(lines)
re.split(r"-", song)
sLists = (song.split("-"))
sList = sLists[0]
sLetter = sLists[0][0]
sWords = sList.split(" ")
sWordAmount = len(sWords)
sOutput = ("")
sGeneration = sList[1:]
for char in sGeneration:
    if char == " ":
        sOutput = sOutput + (" /")
    elif char == "'":
        sOutput = sOutput + (" '")
    elif char == ".":
        sOutput = sOutput + (" .")
    elif char == ",":
        sOutput = sOutput + (" ,")
    elif char == "(":
        sOutput = sOutput + (" (")
    elif char == ")":
        sOutput = sOutput + (" )")
    else:
        for i in range (sWordAmount):
            if char == sWords[i][0]:
                sOutput = sOutput + char
        else:
            sOutput = sOutput + (" _")
print (sLetter + sOutput + " By " + sLists[1])
```

If you need any more info please just ask!

Comment: I'm having a really hard time reading your code; with all due respect this is not very well written; some comments at the very least would be nice. Also, having a bunch of elif statements is very ugly; try looking into how to use dictionaries.

Comment: Your line `re.split(r"-", song)` does not do anything as you do not save the result.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first time posting. My expected output is all the words in the song name to have their first letter shown and the rest be underscores and each space to be displayed with a '/'.

Comment: @umbra57 post few examples of expected output based on condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simplified with `isalpha()` to use an underscore in place of a letter otherwise keep the punctuation.

```
lines = ["All Star-Smash Mouth", "Don't Stop Believin'-Journey", "Mr. Brightside-The Killers"]
song = random.choice(lines)
name, artist = song.split('-')
s = ''
for word in name.split():
    s += word[0] + ' '.join('_' if l.isalpha() else l for l in word[1:]) + ' /'
print(s[:-1] + ' By ' + artist)
```

Answer (score 0):

What u are missing is a break in the `for` loop in your `else` branch.

```
for i in range(sWordAmount):
    if char == sWords[i][0]:
        sOutput = sOutput + char
        break
else:
    sOutput = sOutput + (" _")
```

Excerpt from [Python Tips](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html):

> for loops also have an else clause which most of us are unfamiliar with. The else clause executes after the loop completes normally.

So the first letter of a new word inserted an additional `_`.